# matching a specific word at the end of sentence

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have this regex to check that the sentence in a specified field must end with the outlined letters. Here is the regex expression

```
$scope.pattern = /\b(?:za(?:ZA)?|dtn?|ZA?|DTN)$/;
$scope.error = "must end in za or dtn"
```

the above idea is that field with the model "pattern" must end in either za or ZA or dtn or DTN. But at the moment only when it ends with exactly za that the error is flagged

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your RegEx looks unnecessarily complex. Try this:

```
/(za|ZA|dtn|DTN)$/
```

Or this:

```
/(za|dtn)$/i
// Uses the 'i' flag to indicate "case-insensitive"
```

Both of these will match if the input ends with `za`, `ZA`, `dtn`, or `DTN`.

If all you're doing is a simple match, it is not necessary to indicate a `(?:non-capturing group)`.

Answer (score 1):

For handing case you should use (?i) flag rather than making so many combinations for different case of letters. I think you can simply change your regex and write it like this,

```
/(?:\bza|DTN)$/i
```